# External camera doesn't work JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I have a JavaCV application using external camera, but it's not working... The result is a black image from the camera...
I have another project that use the same code and it's works fine...
I don't understando why it's not working in my new project

```
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
imgCamera = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

the code is simple, first capture the image from external webcam and set it in a IplImage

why it works in a project and don't in another?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all your camera attached to your system and then get index for particular device either it is a webcam or external camera and use it in code. I am giving you a sample code for it

```
String cameraInformation = "";
int n = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.videoInput.listDevices();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String info = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.videoInputLib.videoInput
                    .getDeviceName(i);
            //cameraInformation = info + " Device id:" + i + "\n";
            system.out.println("Your information for camera:"+info+" and device index is="+i);
        }
```

From here you come to know which is the index of which device and use it in this code

```
capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(deviceIndex);
imgCamera = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it didin't work... I wanna know why the cam works in an application and doesn't works in another...

Comment: It is because you are hard coding the Device Index in  cvCreateCameraCapture(1); here you are assuming that device index is 1 . So it might not be case if i attach 2 external camera how you will come to know which device you want to access and i think this is the reason. Above code will tell you about which camera have which index then use it accordingly Hope it helps